# Load different script per browser for performance

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I was looking on jsperf at some tests. Some results for common things like trycatch blocks and array functions are not just far apart per browser, sometimes even the total opposite.

So I was thinking, when performance is key, why not load different scripts/modules per browser or pass browser specs as a function parameter to have it choose the best performing implementation for that browser.

What I'm looking for is a way to split up the implementations per browser.

Perhaps [detect the browser runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-platform) and then either:

- specs as parameter and choose within function implementation or
- entirely different scripts/modules per browser

Comment: So you don't really have a programming problem, you are here asking for research/documentation?

Comment: I was. I've revised the question 